# Implementation of toString() method in a linkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I was trying to implement a method that prints out the contents inside a linked list.
Here is an explanation of classes that I use:

1) `NonEmptyListNode` and `EmptyListNode` inherit `AbstractListNode`.
2) a trailing node is represented with the `EmptyListNode`.

I actually implemented it, however, I felt bad since I was taught that `instanceof` keyword is bad. Here are my questions:

1) Can I implement toString() without `instanceof` keyword?
2) Could I implement toString() in a recursive way?

Here is my code:

```
abstract public class AbstractListNode {        
    abstract public Object item();
    abstract public AbstractListNode next();
    abstract public boolean isEmpty();
    abstract public int size();
    abstract public String toString();            
}

class NonemptyListNode extends AbstractListNode {

    private Object myItem;
    private AbstractListNode myNext;

    public NonemptyListNode (Object item, AbstractListNode next) {
        myItem = item;
        if (next == null) {
            myNext = new EmptyListNode();
        } else {
            myNext = next;
        }
    }

    public NonemptyListNode (Object item) {
        this (item, new EmptyListNode());
    }

    public Object item() { return myItem; }

    public AbstractListNode next() { return myNext; }

    public boolean isEmpty() {return false;}

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 1 + myNext.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        AbstractListNode iter = this;
        String str = "( ";

        //HERE
        while(iter instanceof NonemptyListNode){
            str += iter.item() + " ";
            iter = iter.next();
        }
        return str + iter.toString();
    }
}

class EmptyListNode extends AbstractListNode {   
    public EmptyListNode() {}

    public Object item() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("There is no 'item' value stored in an EmptyListNode.");
    }

    public AbstractListNode next() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("No elements follow an EmptyListNode.");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: The `EmptyListNode` class is rather peculiar.  Most implementations of linked lists don't require a special class for the terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
iter instanceof NonemptyListNode
```

with

```
iter.isNonEmpty()
```

or

```
!iter.isEmpty()
```

where this returns `true` for `NonemptyListNode`

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that I already had the method that I needed. Thank you.